# Where does $f(z)=\sin \phi$ continuous? where $z=re^{i\phi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } z=0 \\ \sin \phi \text{ if } z=re^{i\phi} \neq 0 \end{cases}$$
Where does $f$ continuous? I only know the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition about  continuous function, is there a polar form definition of it? Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f({1\over n}e^{i\pi/2})=1$ so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: So any other places do $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that it were, then $|f(z)|<2^{-1}$ for all $|z|\leq\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. Put $z=(\delta/2)e^{i(\pi/6)}$ we have $|f(z)|=\sin(\pi/6)=2^{-1}$, so we end up with $2^{-1}<2^{-1}$, a contradiction.